# Can I use curly brackets in Ruby's if/else?

Tags: ruby

Why can't I use curly brackets in `if`/`else` constructs? I left Python as I didn't feel comfortable with indenting the statements carefully.

Is this the same way in Ruby also?

For example, can I write something like this?

```
if token == "hello" {
  puts "hello encountered"
  # lots of lines here
}
```

Is there any way of using curly brackets to do this? I read about blocks also but not sure how can they be used in `if`/`else` expressions.

Comment: if you are having a hard time with formatting you might want to try using an IDE that can autoformat for you just so you can see how things should look starting out

Comment: @dave need to take another look at it .. with acceptance in mind :)

Comment: I think you're making a mistake here.  You can't bend a language's syntax to your expectations (at least not in Ruby).  Instead, you'll have to bend your expectations to a language's syntax.  It's just part of learning a new language.  And if you don't feel comfortable indenting your code, use a better IDE or editor.  It's something you need to be doing anyway, so it just shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Note that braces/curly brackets don't work in Ruby like they do in, e.g Java/C/C++/C# - there's a whole different concept (blocks) involved

Comment: Considering that you can use either `end` or braces for blocks, I'm kind of curious why you can't do so for conditionals.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: `end` is a generic keyword that ends a context (conditionals, class and module definitions, method definitions, loops and exception-catching blocks). Curly braces are special syntax for defining blocks or Hashes.

Answer (score 16):

You can't use curly braces, but indentation doesn't matter either. Instead of a closing brace, Ruby uses the `end` keyword.

```
if token == "hello"
  puts "hello encountered"
  # lots of lines here
end
```

I'd still recommend indenting carefully, though — poorly indented code will trick human readers even if braces are used correctly.

Comment: +1 for stressing the importance of proper indention over braces. Raedability is king.

Comment: @iAdam: I'm sorry — what gets messy for big constructs?

Comment: @iAdam: You mean if you have many indentation levels? That's why you should refactor your code into small and readable portions ie. methods.

Comment: if you have a big construct, your construct is doing too much. Maybe take a quick look at common code smells: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell

Comment: Yes, indentation gets messy for big "constructs."  But that just means your code isn't very good.  Huge, long methods with multiple levels of loops and conditionals isn't Ruby's style.  Instead, break down each part into smaller methods that serve single purposes and are easy to understand.  Compose larger tasks from these methods, and this confusing indentation problem will disappear.

Comment: Conventionally, how many spaces is "correct indentation"? I'm doing codeacademy which says 2 spaces (in if blocks) against the normal 4 in python.

Comment: @Manish: Two spaces is the standard in Ruby. Four is normal in Python and most other languages.

Answer (score 15):

This is cute:

```
def my_if(condition, &block)
    block.call if condition
end
```

Use as follows:

```
my_if(token == "hello") { 
    puts "hello encountered!" 
}
```

Comment: For even more fun, define `if` on `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` as Smalltalk does.

Comment: This is beautiful and such smart thinking.

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You need to use `end` instead of a `}`.