# Ruby for in loop error with { } block delimiter

Tags: ruby

In the language Ruby the following works in irb

```
for fruit in ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date'] do
    puts fruit 
end
```

but this one does not

```
# error
for fruit in ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date'] { puts fruit }
```

please note for reference the following block delimiters do not error

```
5.times do |i|
    puts "hello "+i.to_s
end

5.times { |i| puts "hello "+i.to_s }
```

Edit: I guess what I'm observing is an inconsistency with the way do end is substituted for { } can someone explain why or please point out my mistake?

Comment: don't know why, but there is a similar restriction in `refine <class> do` as well.

Comment: If it's any consolation, you don't need the opening `do` in a `for` loop.

Comment: This might be to do with the fact that `for` and `while` (which acts like `for`) are not methods. But I await a formal reasoning.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why we should _always avoid and consider being a code smell_ `for` and `while` loops in ruby.

Comment: I cannot find where `for` is defined in the official Ruby doc. Does somebody know where it is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following quote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711344/can-i-use-curly-brackets-in-rubys-if-else) post explains the "inconsistency" well (emphasis mine):

> `end` is a generic keyword that ends a context (conditionals, class and module definitions, method definitions, loops and exception-catching [statements]). **Curly braces are special syntax for defining blocks or Hashes**.

`for` loops are control structures - not methods with a block argument - hence they must be closed with the `end` keyword. Methods such as`Enumerable#times` and `Enumerable#each` have a block argument which can be defined with either of the `{ }` or `do ... end` syntaxes.

Comment: great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`for` isn't a method defined for [Object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Object.html) or in [Kernel](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html), and it doesn't expect a block.

You cannot write :

```
class A {
  def method {
  }
}
```

either.

You could define a custom `my_for` method :

```
module Kernel
  def my_for(elements, &block)
    elements.each(&block)
  end
end

my_for ['apple','banana','cherry', 'date'] do |fruit|
  puts fruit
end

my_for ['apple','banana','cherry', 'date'] { |fruit| puts fruit }
```

Comment: `for ... in` is a valid control expression in Ruby, see the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-for+Loop).